# Possible to set Firestore id on create via Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to set the id of a Firestore record via Cloud Functions? My use case is converting a title field to a slug and using that as the id of the record, using Functions to enforce uniqueness by appending an integer to the slug as needed. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You determine the ID of any document when you first create that document:

```
db.collection('cities').doc('new-city-id').set(data);
```

So the document ID above is `new-city-id`. If you want to generate an ID, you call `add(...)` instead of `doc('new-city-id').set(...)`, so:

```
db.collection('cities').add(data);
```

But you cannot change the ID of an existing document.

So if you're triggered off a document that has already been created, there's no way to change its ID.

Comment: Can I have my own id, I want to set a property as ID and it's unique.